# How can i load text file in python

Tags: python

How can I load the following text file in Python which contains the 
points in the list within list form.
The following contains the file is already in list form which python 
read as it is

The file is d0.txt

```
[(  0.,   0.,  5.) ( 10.,   0.,  5.) (  0.,  10.,  5.)]
```

Any suggestion and help is appreciated

Comment: Did you just dump the output of some `print` call to a `.txt` file? *Why*? You should take a minute to think about how you are serializing your data and then you won't have to roll your own parser every time...

Comment: Please have a look over this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46183575/how-can-i-print-the-output-list-into-text-file

Comment: You need to take a step back. Your questions are great examples of the [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). That is, you keep asking "how do I do this" but you *really just want to serialize and deserialize a `numpy.ndarray`*. For that, you should use the [*built-in serialization format*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html). So all you want is `np.save(file_name, my_array)` and then to get it back, `my_array = np.load(file_name)`.

Comment: And **just as I suspected** you were simply dumping the string representation of your `numpy.ndarray` to a text file: `f.writelines ( str ( d ) + '\n' )`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
data = ast.literal_eval(open('d0.txt').read())
```

I'm assuming you have a typo in the string (you're missing commas between tuples).

Comment: You are assuming too much. This looks like a dump of a `str` call on a structured `np.ndarray`. So try: `mytype = np.dtype([('a',np.float,), ('b', np.float,), ('c',np.float,)])` and then `print(np.array([(  0.,   0.,  5.), ( 10.,   0.,  5.), (  0.,  10.,  5.)],dtype=mytype))`

Comment: Anyway, perhaps I was too quick to judge, but I saw high rep, but just checked and I guess you just recently started contributing regularly to the Python tag, but *given your assumption* you should have flagged this as a duplicate for [this well known target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list-in-python)

Comment: yes under the assumption of course it works! Also I don't consider your answer false since what the OP posted is not valid python syntax.

Comment: Please have a look over this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46183575/how-can-i-print-the-output-list-into-text-file